# RecyclerView Android - чат наподобие WhatsApp

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Пишу чат наподобие WhatsApp, использую для вывода инфо с сервера `RecyclerView`.

Как мне сделать, чтобы с появлением новой информации `RecyclerView` двигалась вниз? Заранее блогадарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто проскролить до последнего элемента в списке как-то так:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,помогло!

Comment: @OPTIMIST.KZ, если один из предложенных ответов решил ваш проблему, то вы можете отметит его верным, нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)

Comment: нажимаю но они говорят чтобы у меня не хватает рейтинга

Comment: @OPTIMIST.KZ, это вы пытаетесь на стрелочку вверх нажать - для неё надо 15 репутации. А снизу есть галочка - на неё то и надо нажать)

Comment: Все понел спасибо!нажал)